# Coming up with an example of a subspace that is not closed.

Tags: vector-spaces, power-series

I am trying to include the fact that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Perhaps I could use $C[0,1]$ as a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$(or some bigger space?), and then view $\{x_N\}=\{\sum_{n=0}^{N} x^n\}$ as example of a sequence which has it's limit not in $C[0,1]$, but where all of the terms are?

Is this thinking correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Subspace of what type of space (what structure) and closed in what sense (topologically?)

Comment: Because if we are talking topologically there are very trivial examples of subspaces that are not closed.

Comment: I mean it as a vector space. I am not sure what it means to speak topologically.

Comment: If you're talking about limits, that's topology. The structure we're working with is both a vector space that we can add and scalar multiply in and a topological space that we can find open or closed sets and take limits in. And that leads to the question - how are we defining the topology?

Comment: You should mention all of that in your question. Also, it technically doesn't make sense to ask for a 'subspace' that fails closure, because a subspace satisfies closure. How about asking for a subset that fails closure? Do you want it to fail closure over addition of vectors or scaling by scalars?

Comment: Perhaps I have gotten a bit ahead of myself here... I am quite unfamiliar with topology. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, it is not clear what exactly you want an example of, but I think it sounds like you are seeking a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, with a subset $U \subset V$ such that $U$ fails to be a vector space?

If so, let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual vector space structure over $\mathbb{R}$.

Take $U$ to be the upper half plane, $$U = \{\, (x,y) \, | \, y \geq 0 \, \}.$$ $U$ fails to be a subspace for it fails closure when vectors are acted on by scalars. This can be easily checked by seeing, $(-1) \cdot (1,1) = (-1,-1) \not\in U$, for example.

For failing closure of addition of vectors, take $U$ to be the subset that is quadrant 1 union quadrant 3, $$U = \{ \, (x,y) \, | \, x, y \geq 0 \text{ or } x, y\leq 0 \, \}.$$ The vectors $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are in $U$ but $(-1,0) + (0,1) = (-1,1)$ is not.